# how to process an upload file in mootools?

Tags: php, ajax, mootools

I already search about this and I cannot use ajax in file uploading, but all I need to do is process my file through an ajax then pass it to my controller (where I created and object file to save in a directory), so how can I process an upload file trough an ajax mootols, I already do it and nothings happens,  no plugins please, I need just to someone guide me

this is my code

```
       #f1_upload_process{
           z-index:100;
           position:absolute;
           visibility:hidden;
           text-align:center;
           width:400px;
           margin:0px;
           padding:0px;
           background-color:#fff;
           border:1px solid #ccc;
       }
       </style>



   <p id="f1_upload_process">Loading...<br/></p>

   <p id="result"></p>

    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">   

        <label for="file">Subir un archivo</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="fileArchivo" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btnSubir" value="upload file" />  

   <iframe name="iframUpload" id="iframeUpload" type="file" style="display:none"></iframe>


        </form>
```

mootools ajax

```
window.addEvent("domready",function(){
    cargarIndex();                                
});


function cargarIndex()
{   
   var prueboRequest = new Request({
   method: 'POST', 
   url: '../CONTROLLER/inicio.php',
   onRequest: function() {}, 
   onSuccess: function(texto, xmlrespuesta){
   document.getElementById('subirarchivo').innerHTML= texto;
   $('btnSubir').addEvent('click',function(){beginUploading()});  
   },
   onFailure: function(){alert('Error!');}  
   }).send();


}

function beginUploading(){

   var prueboRequest = new Request({
   method: 'POST', 
   url: '../Controller/ControllerSubirArchivo.php',
   onRequest: function() {}, 
   onSuccess: function(texto, xmlrespuesta){
   onFailure: function(){alert('Error!');}  
   }).send();
```

I already search but all I have found is this but with jquery, and I want something similar to:

```
$(function(){
    var btnUpload=$('#upload');
    var status=$('#status');
    new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
        action: 'upload-file.php',
        //Name of the file input box
        name: 'uploadfile',
        onSubmit: function(file, ext){
            if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){
                  // check for valid file extension
                status.text('Only JPG, PNG or GIF files are allowed');
                return false;
            }
            status.text('Uploading...');
        },
        onComplete: function(file, response){
            //On completion clear the status
            status.text('');
            //Add uploaded file to list
            if(response==="success"){
                $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="./uploads/'+file+'" alt="" /><br />'+file).addClass('success');
            } else{
                $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text(file).addClass('error');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

}

Comment: http://mootools.net/forge/p/uploadmanager ?

Comment: thanks but thats no what I am looking for, when you want to upload a file what needs to be procesed  in javascript or in a mootools ajax thats my question, I just want a message says the the file is stored but I am lost in mootools, I have searched but nothing seems to work

Comment: Whatever handler you end up using will have some kind of "oncomplete" type callback, which is where you'd put your "everything worked ok" notification stuff.

Comment: how did you do it without plugins? any advise I am a bit lost in ajax mootools

Comment: ERM. USE PLUGINS. you have an api for uploading files via html5 - google it, eg http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/ for the standard but look at tutorials. since HTML5 is not cross browser, as a fallback you can use flash. the plugin recommended does both. at the very least, look at the source of the plugins to see what is required and how to mod the Request class. if you are not well versed with js and mootools, it will not be straightforward.

Comment: I still dont figure out why plugins? can someone explain why its so difficult program since 0 a upload file ajax or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dimitar Christoff said, no way to have an ajax file upload without a little bit of cross browser headache for now…
I would recommend the plupload project so you're sure it's cross browser. A plugin from the forge could also do the trick but separating the javascript file upload library is a good idea these days. Considering that the implementation of the HTML5 API is still partial on a lot of browsers, you may have to update the script soon…